# How can I write Cucumber scenarios in German?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, locale

For my current project I need Cucumber scenarios to be in German.

Is there any easy way to use instead of: Background, Scenario, Given, When, Then, And... their German translation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `# language: de` to first line.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Spoken-languages